# How to get current Python DLL?

Tags: python, dll, python-3.x

I want to load current Python DLL via ctypes. I can load it like ctypes.windll.python33 but that depends on current version. I know that there is its handle in sys.dllhandle, but I don't know how to transform the handle in ctypes DLL object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe better ctypes.pythonapi ?

code from `ctypes/__init__.py`

```
if _os.name in ("nt", "ce"):
    pythonapi = PyDLL("python dll", None, _sys.dllhandle)
elif _sys.platform == "cygwin":
    pythonapi = PyDLL("libpython%d.%d.dll" % _sys.version_info[:2])
else:
    pythonapi = PyDLL(None)
```

If you want to load library by handle:

```
hndl = sys.dllhandle
pythondll = ctypes.CDLL('python dll',  handle=hndl)
```

PyDLL and WinDll subclasses CDll and differs by _func_flags_ attribute.